# Edge firewall on Ubuntu, dynamic IP address, static DNS

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ip, dhcp

We're setting up a software firewall, and one of the issues we're facing is that eth0 has a dynamic IP address.

In /etc/network/interfaces we've got the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# internet-facing interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    dns-nameservers 192.168.5.8 192.168.5.5
    dns-search -------.local

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.5.252
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.5.0
    broadcast 192.168.5.255
    dns-nameservers 192.168.5.8 192.168.5.5
    dns-search -------.local

# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth1 inet6 auto
```

The problem is that resolv.conf ends up with the DNS IP's of our ISP...

**Update** As stated above, resolv.conf gets the DNS IP addresses of our ISP that are part of the DHCP Package. The idea is that we get just an IP address, but basically only use our internal DNS servers. So the DNS parameters of DHCP should be ignored. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: So, what is your problem ? cannot understand

Comment: He wants to use his own DNS servers instead of the ISP dhcp discovered ones and the DNS servers in the eth0 network stub are being overridden.

Comment: @Shutupsquare Sorry, i don't have my crystal ball under hands ;)

Comment: @user2196728 The first time I read it I didn't get the problem till I read the config.

Comment: @Shutupsquare Ok great ! BTW i am glad to see that i was not the only one thinking that it was unclear ! Feel free to reword the question to  make it more clear and stop the "on hold" status

Comment: There is a relevant article that discusses this same issue [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StaticDnsWithDhcp)

Comment: @Shutupsquare, thank you for this link, I'll give this a try and get back on this.

Comment: @Shutupsquare - You hit the nail right on the head, the article solved my problem :)